# How to use vandelay tag cloud in Orchard CMS blog?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I am trying to use Vandelay Industries Module in Orchard CMS Blog.

Here's a link for it:

http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Vandelay.Industries

I have the all the module features enabled in admin but I am not getting the tag cloud seeing the standard  tags. I am yet to test the other yet.

Is there something other than just enabling it supposed to be in order to make it work? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for the help.

I can provide screen shots if required(Stackoverflow needs 10 points to upload images so couldn't upload it this time)

Comment: I don't understand "I am not getting the tag cloud seeing the standard tags". Do you see the widget in the widget section of the admin? If not, try to get the latest version from http://vandelay.codeplex.com/

Comment: Sorry about that.. would have been clearer with images.. My admin module setting looks like this <http://i.imgur.com/M5fdT.png> and the tag cloud looks like this <http://i.imgur.com/RGCP9.png>.. Please let me know if you need more info and yes I have the latest version. thanks

Comment: Also I dont see any widget by name Vandelay. I just see Tags Cloud one. I think that is built in one. Thanks.. like this http://i.imgur.com/WSBe2.png

Comment: There is no built-in tag cloud. The one you're seeing is the one from Vandelay. See my answer below on styling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to style the tag cloud in your theme css. Here is what I use on my own site:

```
/* Tag Cloud */
ul.tagCloud { list-style: none; }
li.tagCloud-tag { display: inline; }
.tagCloud-tag a { border: none; }
.tagCloud-1 { font-size: 1em; }
.tagCloud-2 { font-size: 1.1em; }
.tagCloud-3 { font-size: 1.2em; }
.tagCloud-4 { font-size: 1.3em; }
.tagCloud-5 { font-size: 1.4em; }
.tagCloud-6 { font-size: 1.5em; }
.tagCloud-7 { font-size: 1.6em; }
.tagCloud-8 { font-size: 1.7em; }
.tagCloud-9 { font-size: 1.8em; }
.tagCloud-10 { font-size: 1.9em; }
```